# how to handle swapping a view when device rotates on iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation

So I followed the following tutorial on creating custom views associated with device orientations:

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/30/orientation-change-tutorial-change-the-view-when-the-orientation-changes/

To summarize the article, the author is able to generate custom views for landscape and portrait orientations by pointing to a new top level view in an XIB file upon detecting a device rotation.

Therefore, I took a complicated view hierarchy (many buttons, sliders, views within views), duplicated everything at the top level to create the landscape view. Then created custom arrangements for the landscape view. In a method where my code detects a landscape orientation, my code points to the top of the landscape hierarchy and portrait when detecting portrait.

This works, except all the IBOutlets (UIView, UIButton, etc) in landscape hierarchy are still referencing their equivalent objects in portrait view hierarchy. I do a lot of special processing on these UI elements during the run time so I require IBOutlets and not just IBActions. I found that my copied UI elements in the landscape view can point to the same IBActions, but they can not share IBOutlets with the ones in the portrait hierarchy.

Do I have to duplicate all the objects and have my code manage everything (figure out which objects to use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that may suit you.

If you load the landscape nib right at the time when you need to swap in the landscape view, you can pass your view controller as the nib file's owner, and the nib loader will overwrite your view controller's outlets based on the connections in the landscape nib.

And when you need to swap in the portrait view again, load the portrait nib and pass the view controller as the file's owner.  The nib loader will again overwrite your view controller's outlets, this time based on the connections in the portrait nib.

You should lazily create a `UINib` object for each of the nibs the first time that nib is needed, and keep them around to speed up loading on subsequent rotations.

Comment: Sure Ill try it out in a bit. So I get what I need to do is 1. duplicate the .xib file (can do it in Finder app). 2. Rearrange the layout. 3. load my landscape nib at the appropriate time...is it with this call? "- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options".... and thats it??

Comment: You can use that method.  If you find that it is too slow, you should look at `UINib`.

Comment: I tried that method, the call is:         [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyLandscapeOrPortraitNib" owner:self options:nil];
inside - (void) orientationChanged:(id)object (depending on if it detected landscape/portrait). However, when the new nib gets loaded, I see only some of my content and my application crashes fairly soon after (due to the lack of that content). Now what I've noticed, is that if i comment out the nib loading lines, then my application runs 100% fine on portrait mode. Then when I add in the nib, I get missing content in both landscape and portrait.

Comment: So this is what I just did, if I use initWithNibName on either the landscape or portrait view at the time the app starts up, then that works perfectly. However if I do loadNibNamed under orientationChanged, then I get the new layout with a bunch of uninitialized stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using loadNibNamed. Essentially what I had to do was save the state of all the IBOulet variables (using non IB variables) and other variables that are initialized in the view. When a new Nib is loaded, everything resets back to their default states. It's quite annoying, but this seems to be the best way to approach this for now.